# Запись в поток значения по указателю

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в третьей строке выводится что то в шестнадцатеричном виде.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Something {
private:
    string m_somenumber;
public:
    Something(string somenumber) {
        m_somenumber = somenumber;
    }
};

class Thing {
private:
    int m_id;
    string m_name;
    Something* m_smth;
public:
    Thing(int id, string name) {
        m_id = id;
        m_name = name;
    }

    void setSmth(Something* smth) {
        m_smth = smth;
    }

    void info() {
        cout << m_id << endl;
        cout << m_name << endl;
        cout << m_smth << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Thing* thing = new Thing(1, "Name");
    Something* smth1 = new Something("text");
    thing->setSmth(smth1);
    thing->info();
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получаю:
 - 1 
 - Name
 - **0x950fe0**

Comment: Указатель не разыменовал?

Comment: Вот-вот. Вы выводите значение указателя, что ж вы прикажете выводить?